# which of the following spaces are locally compact:

Tags: general-topology

Is  the following space are locally compact:

$X_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x,y $ are both even$\}$

I  feel it is not so  because if any point $(x,y)$ is chosen then we have a find closed and bounded subset totally contained in $X_1$ which is not possible to find .Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_1=\{\langle 2m,2n\rangle:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$; this is a discrete space, since $B(p,1)\cap X_1=\{p\}$ for each $p\in X_1$. Thus, $X_1$ is locally compact: for each $p\in X_1$, $\{p\}$ is a compact open nbhd of $p$ in $X_1$. If you want to express this in terms of the metric,

$$\{p\}=B\left(p,\frac12\right)=\operatorname{cl}B\left(p,\frac12\right)\;.$$

Comment: thanks your answer is as satisfying as ever

Comment: @learnmore: You’re welcome.